# Angular 2 use custom component selector in 3rd party directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm using [ng2-bootsrap's](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) **[accordion directive](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#accordion)**.

It works fine with normal html using this syntax:

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="Heading 1">
        <div>Quick Search...</div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

I would like to insert a selector from one of my components like this:

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="Heading 1">
        <quick-search></quick-search>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

When I add my component, the parser just removes the selector and doesn't show anything in its place. If accordion was a directive that I created, I would normally add my component(QuickSearchComponent) to the list of directives like this:

```
@Component({
   ...
   directives: [QuickSearchComponent]
   ...
})
```

But being that this is a 3rd party Directive. How can make the directive recognize it or add to the @Component.directives annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
directives: [QuickSearchComponent]
```

is required on the component that contains

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="Heading 1">
        <quick-search></quick-search>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

and is not necessary in the `accordion` or `accordion-group` component.

What is necessary in the `accordion-component` is an `<ng-content>` tag where `<quck-search>` is transcluded to.

If it works with `<div>Quick Search...</div>` then it should work with `<quick-search></quick-search>` as well.

The problem is caused by something else.